# Java - turning an ArrayList to an Array

Tags: java, arraylist

Why does the code compile when I'm turning an `ArrayList` to an `objectArray` and does **NOT** compile when I'm turning an `ArrayList` to an `stringArray` (just if I mention "`new String[0]`")???

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("George");
    list.add("John");
    Object[] objectArray = list.toArray();
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(objectArray));
    String[] stringArray = list.toArray(new String[0]);
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(objectArray));
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to print `stringArray` in the second `println`.

Comment: you need to pass array object as parameter , but you are essentially passing a String object

Comment: If posting a question about a compiler error, you should include the error message.

Comment: Check the returned type. `List.toArray()` return an `Object[]`. You need to pass a specific array to use the generic method to get it right

Comment: Your exact code compiles and runs fine for me.

Comment: @smarx, _(just if I mention "new String[0]")_ means that this is only compiling when he add this line ;) I had to read this multiple time to get it

Comment: Then I guess the original poster hasn't told us what code he's actually having trouble with (or what error he's getting). I'll vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short, here are the signature of both methods for [java.util.List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

```
Object[] toArray()
```

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element).

```
<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)
```

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper sequence (from first to last element); the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.

So this is logic to get an error if you tried to store an `Object[]` into a `String[]`

You need to pass an array to specify the type. You should set the length directly, the methods can do it but you will do it easily

```
new String[list.length]
```

Comment: Thx a lot AxelH, your explanation is very good!!!